# Getting typeahead to work in an Angular template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I currently have a partial HTML that is being routed to, with a template and a custom Controller. The code snippet in my Angular template I would like to get working is:

`<input type="text" typeahead=val for val in getValue($viewValue)>`

However, it never enters into the function getValue(), while all other functions in my controller seem to be okay. When I take the typeahead out of the Angular template/partial, it seems to work. Why is this and how do I fix it?

Comment: There is not enough code here to answer your question. Could you post some code from your controller, like the getValue method?

Comment: Which third party module are you using to provide the `typeahead` attribute directive? [AngularUI](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead)?

Comment: Yes, I am using angularUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have an `ng-model` attribute to use the [`typeahead` directive](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) from [AngularUI](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), even if you don't need to bind it to anything.

Change your markup to similar to the following:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="typeaheadVal" typeahead="val for val in getValue($viewValue)">
```

Comment: You will need to provide more code then. Ideally, try to supply a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co) or [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).